# Meteor Iron:Router Problems Getting ID

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Can someone explain why am i getting the full value of ObjectID instead just the clean ID?

This is what i'm getting:

[image]

And the HTML output:

```
<a href="/summary/ObjectID(%2254ab87a24c38814aa128da7b%22)">My Post</a>
```

I haven't done anything out of the ordinary. Very basic stuff right now. Just trying out Meteor for the first time.

**Routing: lib/router.js**

```
// Dashboard
Router.route('/dashboard', {name: 'dashboard'});

// Post detail
Router.route('/summary/:_id', {
    name: 'postSummary',
    data: function() {
        return Post.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

**List page template: templates/posts/post_dashboard.html**

```
{{#each posts}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><a href="{{pathFor 'postSummary'}}">{{title}}</a></p>
            <p><small>Created at {{createdAt}}</small></p>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

**Detail page template: templates/posts/post_summary.html**

```
<template name="postSummary">
    {{> postHeader}}

    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</template>
```

**Template helper: templates/posts/posts.js**

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
    posts: function () {
        return Post.find({});
    }
});
```

And here's the packages i have installed, just in case it's necessary.

```
meteor-platform
autopublish
insecure
matthew:foundation5-sass
iron:router
jquery
useraccounts:core
useraccounts:foundation
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
accounts-google
accounts-ui-unstyled
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
forwarder:autoform-wizard
fortawesome:fontawesome
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you query the `Posts` collection from the console, is the `_id` in the returned document(s) a string literal or an ObjectId Object?

Assuming it's the latter, that's why this is happening, and if so, it's probably going to be because you've populated the collection by using `insert` in the Mongo shell (or alternatively restored from an existing MongoDB).  By default, Meteor insert uses strings for the auto-added id when the id is not specified, whereas Mongo uses ObjectIds.

Hope that helps, but let me know if I'm on totally the wrong track!

Comment: yep. i've inserted the data via mongo shell. anyway, i just did a `meteor reset` and tried to insert data via browser console and script instead. but both returns `insert failed: Error: Sample is required`.

Comment: Is that because it's in a schema you've defined with Collection2, but not the item you're trying to insert?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. what's this Collection2?

Comment: one of the packages you've supplied in the list above.

Comment: ahh.. yes. i've defined a collection schema separately for the "create post" form. so this means i have to follow that schema. is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly - it won't let you insert anything from within Meteor that doesn't satisfy the schema.  Obviously that's irrelevant when you do it straight into the MongoDB via the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo ObjectID has a property: `_str` It includes string representation of the ID.

Comment: hmm.. maybe i'm just stupid. but `this.params._id._str` still returns the full ObjectId.

Comment: Hmm. Your Post collection is weird ;P How do you insert documents into it?

Comment: Ok - i looked now on above comments and now it is clearer to me :) When you will insert documents **NOT** using a mongo shell it should work fine for you.